# How to find a proper selector of the HTML elemtn using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a button in html below that has class 'hapus'. When I executed

> alert($(this).closest("li").html());

It produces alert like this:

```
JENIS AKTIVA: 
<button class="btn-link input-xs tambah" type="button" style="display: none;">
   <a>+ tambah</a>
</button>
<div class="tingkat form-group form-inline"><br><button type="button" class="hapus form-group form-inline btn btn-sm btn-danger input-xs">X</button><select class="form-control form-control-sm input-xs turunan" style="width: 160px; margin-left: 2px;" required="" disabled=""><option disabled="" selected="" value="4">Infrastruktur dan Alat Non Medis</option></select> Ket: <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm input-xs" style="margin-left: 7px;" name="125" value=""></div>
```

The question is how can I check if the html of "li" I targeted contains the word 'JENIS AKTIVA'?

Comment: check the innerHTML (in jquery speak that's `.html()`) or textContent (jquery `.text()`) for that string

Comment: So how I write the condition inside the if()? If it contains that said word?

Comment: what `if`? you have no `if` in the code ... strings have methods like `indexOf` or `includes` that will help

Comment: Sorry for not including it. But I wrote how to check which I thought it would mean that I wanted an if clause. I ended using .include() thanks for the help.

Comment: if you used `.include()` then it wouldn't work - it's `.includes()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

`$(this).closest("li").text().includes('JENIS AKTIVA')`

Which will return `true` or `false`, which you can use in an if statement.

Comment: It works. I've tried $(this).closest(li:contains()) but it is a selector, it's not returning a boolean value that can be evaluated. Also I found that .html().includes() works too. Appreciate the answer, I'll accept your answer ASAP.

Comment: contains method is for the selector, what the above is doing is parsing as text, and using the standard [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check it includes the string. you could use .html() but it contains all the dom.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing against a regular expression.

```
 element = $(this).closest("li").html();
 myRegEx = /\s+JENIS AKTIVA\s+/i;
 console.log(myRegEx.test(element))
```

That should return either true or false.

Comment: I'd put `\s+` between JENIS and AKTIVA too - you never know what is producing a single space in a web page :p

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but it seems have the same desired output as .include(). I choose the .include() because it requires less effort and can be read easily by me. Thanks for the answer though, appreciate it.